# I just noticed 40 "leave open" votes in less than 10min, just after midnight

Tags: discussion, review, moderation, users, review-abuse

By some user in StackOverflow.

Should I report this? How?

Comment: Well, you just did.

Comment: @WesleyMurch ;-)

Comment: If you think a user is inappropriately rushing through reviews, just flag for moderator attention using the "Other" option. You can flag anything really. Even your own questions/answers. As long as you clearly state what the problem is and link to the user you're talking about.

Comment: true. Not only is it unlikely to have 40 "leave open" in a row, but also almost impossible to review them in 11 minutes (almost 1 thread every each 15 seconds).

Comment: I can review one thread in 15 seconds - but the chances of all of them needing to be left open are somewhere between slim and none.

Comment: This might be the first time I've heard of a robo-reviewer that I think might be an *actual robot*.

Comment: @Undo The chances of even 2 being "Leave Open" is pretty rare. In addition, let's not forget audits. 40 reviews with no audits?

Comment: If you filter, you don't get an audit.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: wouldn't that be a bug?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely report this. Visit the user's profile, select any random post of theirs, and cast a custom flag explaining that you believe they are abusing their review privileges and why.

This user will be taking a one-month break from review...

Comment: May we know who?

Comment: @ColeJohnson its rather easy - even for a low rep user (don't need 10k review history browsing until the reviews fall out of recent activity for the day - reviews are public info).  Go to the /reviews page for close votes, look at who has done 40 reviews in the past time (note, this is very time sensitive in that when more people do 40 reviews, it will be harder to find), pick a person who's done 40 reviews, go to the activity - reviews page of their profile and look.

Comment: @ColeJohnson so you can't go to http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats ?

Comment: @MichaelT I do believe that if you're review banned you get completely blocked from the entire /review path. I remember users complaining before that they couldn't access the stats while banned.

Comment: Here the link: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1003917/shankar-damodaran?tab=activity&sort=reviews